# Is it allowed to transform x and y in an ANCOVA?

Tags: data-transformation, ancova

in my ANCOVA analysis, I have the case that my Y and X show a nonlinear pattern. Transforming either only Y or X does not help to stabilize variance. I did not find any hint that doing an ANCOVA in log-log space is illegal, however, I also did not find any note on that one should try out a  transformation of Y AND X...

Could someone give me a hint if I am doing wrong with log-log?

thanks!

Comment: Because ANCOVA is just a form of linear regression, you will find useful replies by searching on the [regression and data-transformation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-transformation+regression) tags.

Comment: Thanks, I found out that log(Y+2) already helped to stabilize the residuals. I used the logtrans function from the MASS package in R to come to this conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

I found that sometimes in necessary to "linearized" the relationship between X and Y. if you have an allometric relationship or for instance a power function, a log-log trasnformation help to do that and also ofcourse help to stabilize variances. it all depends in the nature of your data